# Why is PMD give different results for Eclipse and Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I am using the [eclipse-pmd](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-pmd) plugin, and I am also using PMD via the following Gradle configuration:

```
plugins {
  id 'pmd'
}

pmd {
  consoleOutput = true
  ruleSets = []
  ruleSetFiles = files("pmd-ruleset.xml")
  toolVersion = "6.41.0"
}
```

Both methods are configured to use the same ruleset, and my `PATH` variable points to PMD 6.41.0 (which I *think* is what the Eclipse plugin uses), and yet both give different results.

For example, running `./gradlew pmdMain` complains about the rule `AvoidUncheckedExceptionsInSignatures`, but eclipse-pmd does not flag this up at all.

Why might this be?

Comment: I don't think that the eclipse-pmd plugin is using the same PMD that you added in Gradle build. Usually these plugins come with everything-packaged, you should check in the installation folder of Eclipse and you'll probably find a plugin folder with the PMD that Eclipse is actually using.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ That sounds promising, but I can't seem to find where the PMD plugin is installed. I've checked `{workspace}/.metadata`, `~/.eclipse` and the Eclipse install directory, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Nevermind, found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the **eclipse-pmd** plugin (which I found in `C:\Users\{username}\.p2\pool\plugins`) comes packaged with its own version of PMD, which in this case is 6.28.0.

This doesn't fully explain the discrepency, since the `AvoidUncheckedExceptionsInSignatures` rule has been around since PMD 6.13.0, but I'm happy enough to blame the difference in versions for the difference in output.